# Change layer to a raster image object in Eagle

Tags: eaglecad, cad

I have a project in eagle cad with an image in bmp which I imported some months ago.

I have it in the top layer and I want to move it to the bottom one, but I can't find the way to change its layer.

What should I do?

Comment: This question is on-topic and specific.  "Too easy" is not a valid close reason.

Comment: To me the question looks legitimate, even though for some might be trivial. But even if it weren't, please keep a respectful tone (to everyone).

Comment: Sorry for my deleted post. I should't have said that.

Answer (score 2):

Look up CHANGE LAYER (HELP CHANGE LAYER).

Comment: There should be a badge "Shows amazing restraint" :)

Comment: @BrianOnn  Moderators should kill threads like this as soon as possible, before they cause neurological damage to highly trained engineers.

Comment: I detect a slight note of irritation in the caps, but other than that.. +1

Comment: Thank you. I already knew the button with a tool and the option change layer but after clicking it, eagle ask you about select with left button the component you want to change, and clicking it makes no diference. the component doesn't change and keeps in its layer.

Comment: -1 I've mainly used Protel but have successfully made a few boards with Eagle. I just tried this and clicking individual nodes changed them (but would be super tedious) and attempting to group them wiped the image. So being a fairly new Eagle user I didn't find this at all useful.

Comment: I think it might be tough to actually select the bitmap image.  Select everything that you CAN select, which would be circuit elements, and change their layer to some empty layer for swapping purposes.  Go back to the original layer, select EVERYTHING with a selection rectangle, then change the layer to what you want.  Then go back to the swap layer and change those elements back to the original layer

Answer (score 1):

#### Option 1

When you import BMPs using the eagle ULP, they tend to be made of many, many lines which would be tedious to change individually. So In the past I have used the following procedure:

1. Hide ALL layers except for the one that your image is on - that way you don't accidentally select something you don't want
2. Use the group tool to select all of the parts of your image. You can either click and drag to get a square box selection if that is ok, but if your image is within a load of other objects you don't want to select, you can use the group tool to make an arbitrary shape around your object by clicking bit by bit along the line you want to group selection to be (hard to explain, but if you start clicking you'll see what I mean).
3. If you click the spanner (change) button - its on the toolbar next to the group tool - then click "Layer..." in the menu that appears. A window will pop up which allows you to select the destination layer, so click the layer you want and then click OK.
4. Now right-click somewhere in the layout view and in the context menu select "Change: Group". This should move all of the selected objects to the chosen layer.

---

#### Option 2

You may find that the above doesn't work if you imported the image onto one of the signal layers. This is because all of the bits of the image have now become signals which means you can only change them between signal layers - you can't move them to text layers.

There is a sort of 'hack' approach to moving them if this has happened, and it only works for Eagle 6+. If you copy the group you selected in (2), then open a new blank board file and paste in the image. Save that board with a unique filename (don't overwrite your other board!) and close it. Then open the .brd in a text editor like Notepad++.

In the text editor, find and replace the following:

1. Remove all lines that look like `<signal name="...">`
2. Remove all likes that look like `</signal>`
3. Replace all occurrences of `layer="#"` (where the # is the layer number you pasted your image on to) with `layer="48"`
4. At the top of the file there is a  tag inside which is all of the layers used in the document. Make sure you have the following (and if not add it): `<layer number="48" name="Document" color="7" fill="1" visible="yes" active="yes"/>`
5. Find the `<plain>` tag, and move all of the `<wire ... />` tags in the file to be directly below it.
6. Save the file, and open it again in Eagle.

If all has gone will, the image should be present on the board, and crucially, none of the wires will be signal traces, they will all be wires on Layer 48. You can now copy that back into your original board file and use Option 1 to move it all to the correct layer.

---

#### Side Note

Because the imported images are made up of so many wires, they are a pain in the neck to work with. What I usually do is make an Eagle Part which contains the image. I use the following procedure:

1. Import the image into a board file on `Layer 104`. This is important as that is a layer (one of many high-numbered layers) which is allowed to be both in the layout and schematic - meaning it can be copied into the Package and Symbol editors in the Library editor.
2. Select the imported image with the group tool, then copy the group
3. Open a library (Library->Open) - I have a library I use for all my symbols, or you can put it in an existing library, or if you prefer make a new library (Open any library and then do File->New in the library editor).
4. Create a new Package, give it a name, then paste the copied image into it. It should paste fine as it is on a layer compatible with the package editor
5. Use the Change->Layer... tool to move the image to the layer of your choice - e.g. `tDocu` or `tPlace` or something.
6. Create a new Symbol, give it a name, then paste the copied image into it. Again this should paste fine. You don't actually have to paste the image into the symbol, but I like to so that I can see in the schematic what the symbol is going to look like.
7. Change the layer of the image to something like the `Info` layer.
8. Create a new component, add in the symbol and package - because there are no pins, you don't have to connect anything up.
9. Save the library.

If you now tell Eagle to use the new library, you will find you can add the symbol in the schematic of any design and it will also add it to the PCB just like any component. The great thing is that you now don't need to worry about having to select all those hundreds of lines the importbmp ulp created as they are now all grouped together in a component - just move the component to where you want.

This is also a useful approach as it means you can create multiple packages for the same symbol - say you want a large one and a small one, just add another package in the library and add it to your component. Now in the schematic you can select which size symbol you want.

Answer (score 0):

So I know it's been a long time since this has been asked but as Olin suggested looking up HELP CHANGE LAYER didn't help a whole lot. If you just try to use the change layer tool without selecting the proper parts you'll spend all day trying to select the correct parts of the bmp.  It is very difficult to change them one by one.  Yes I know you can group them, but it drops the bmp on top of all your other objects.  Here is the method I use.

```
# Import bmp via ULP rules, apply to new layer.  i.e. 200
display none 200
group all    # or select bitmap via group tool
change layer 22
(> 0 0)
# move to wherever you need/want
display last
```

Perhaps this will be useful to anyone else that is trying to do the same thing.  Took me more time than it should to figure this out.